# Finding that $S_3$ is the homomorphic image of the group with the following presentation

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

I have $G = \langle x,y,z \mid x^2y^4z^3, x^4y^2, x^2y\rangle $.

Now, I have managed to show that its abelianization is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_3$ but I am really stumped as I am trying to find a homomorphism of $G$ onto $S_3$ but I don't really have a clue where to start.

I considered von Dyck's theorem but I am not sure if it can be applied here as the relation set for $G$ is not a subgroup of the relation set for $S_3$.

Any hints are much appreciated.

Comment: Why not pick the trivial homomorphism? I'm not sure what "homomorphic" means, to be honest.

Comment: you can send x to a transposition, y to the identity and z to a 3-cycle - that will give you a surjective homomorphism

Comment: Right you are. I have edited the title. I am actually looking for a homomorphism whose image is $S_3$ (my bad).

Comment: I think I get it, thank you. My understanding of group presentations is very shaky. I am guessing that since the transposition, identity and 3-cycle solve the relations then it must be surjective as G is the free-est group with these properties?

Comment: In Dyck's theorem you do not need any relations for the image group -- just a way to test whether certain expressions give you the identity. You want to find three permutations $\pi_x,\pi_y,\pi_z$ of degree 3 that they satisfy the two relators you give, and that they generate $S_3$ (easily tested as having an orbit of length 3 and an odd permutation. )